# getting 2 elements from xml

Tags: php, xml

how to retrieve both instances of element in an xml file

here is how i have been getting the others

```
    $LargeImage = $xml->Items->Item->LargeImage->URL;
    $author = $xml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Author;
echo ($author);
```

however for $author, there are 2 authors and the element is like this

```
Items->Item->ItemAttributes->
<Author>Ralph Bravaco</Author>
<Author>Shai Simonson</Author>
```

so my current code is only able to get back the first author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($xml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Author as $author) {
    echo (string)$author.'<br>';
}
```

It will echo all authors irrespective of no. of authors.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath('/Items/Item/ItemAttributes/Author');
while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo $node,"\n";
}
```

Comment: this does not return any results,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for this --

```
echo $author = $xml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Author[0];

echo $author = $xml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Author[1];
```

Comment: this will be part of an loop for a larger code so in some cases there are only 1 author some cases there is 3 ect

Comment: @spaceranger you can iterate it using another loop to traverse the depth but for the question you mentioned i think this is the answer :)